# Content Organizer Rule to move documents to Network Share

Tags: 2010

is it possible to write custom organizer rule to move document to network folder share based on metadata or it only work with moving docs between sharepoint libraries and folders.

please advise

Thanks
Ronak

Answer (score 0):

With custom code, you can do this. But if the intent is to store documents on a file share, why even bother with SharePoint?

Comment: Thanks Paul can please advise me how do this as i have seen most of example user Target path to sharepoint list or folder.we are not intend to store in file network and it just for other server to process file to encrypt not sure of exact requirment yet.